# The categories of indefinite pronouns

Tags: grammar, pronouns, terminology, noun-phrases

> I know everything.

> They know all of their pen pals./ They know all the fathers of the
>   family here.

I think "everything" is an indefinite pronoun, and "all" is also an indefinite pronoun, so what makes in grammar that one is always used with a nominal group, and the other one doesn't accept a nominal group.

What are the different categories of indefinite pronouns in grammar, and what are the linguistic concepts making them used with a different grammar structure? Like it's the case here with "all" and "everything"? Being from the same grammatical group, what makes their difference in the linguistic theory?

(This is a grammar question, not about word usage of "everything"/"all".)

Comment: You're starting out on the wrong track. "All" is a determinative, not a pronoun, and "everything" is a compound determinative, not a pronoun. In case you're not familiar with the tern, "determinative' is a word category (part of speech).

Comment: @BillJ: Wikipedia [lists both words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_pronoun#Table_of_indefinite_pronouns), so this is clearly not an isolated misconception.

Comment: @BillJ You might take a look at [this paper](http://www.humanities.manchester.ac.uk/medialibrary/llc/files/david-denison/Bergamo_14ICEHL.pdf). It's making me reconsider my adherence to the CGEL 'fused-head' model in ways I'm frankly not at all comfortable with--which is usually a sign that the authors are on to something! :)

Comment: @StoneyB I'll take a look.

Answer (score -1):

**All** and **Everything** can either act as *an indefinite pronoun* or *an indefinite determiner*.

Compare:

1. **All good books are expensive.** - Here **"all"** acts as *an indefinite determiner*.
2. **All are healthy.** - Here **"all"** acts as *an indefinite pronoun*.

We can use **"all"** alone as **a pronoun** in formal situations. Usually, **"all"** as a pronoun is premodified or postmodified.

**"All"** can also act as a **predeterminer** and comes before articles, possessives, demonstratives and numbers *(such as 'the', 'my', 'this', 'one' or 'his')*:

3. **All the children were playing.**

When **"all"** refers to a whole class of people or things, we don’t use articles, possessives, demonstratives or numbers:

4. **All children are born naked.**

We don’t use articles, possessives, demonstratives or numbers with time expressions such as *'all day', 'all night', 'all week', 'all year', 'all summer'*:

5. **I spent all day looking for my car keys.**

We use all of before personal pronouns (us, them), demonstrative pronouns *(this, that, these, those)* and relative pronouns *(whom, which)*. The personal pronoun is in the object form. With demonstratives *(this, that, these, those)* we can say all of or all without of. We often use of after all in definite noun phrases *(i.e. before the, possessives and demonstratives)*, but it is not obligatory:

6. **He bought ice-cream for all of us.**
7. **All *(of)* these books are old.**
8. **All *(of)* the computers in this room have an Intel chipset.**

> A **pronoun** can be thought of as replacing a noun phrase, while a **determiner** introduces a noun phrase and precedes any adjectives that modify the noun.

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner) says:

> A **determiner**, also called **determinative** *(abbreviated det)*, is a word, phrase, or affix that occurs together with a noun or noun phrase and serves to express the reference of that noun or noun phrase in the context. That is, a determiner may indicate whether the noun is referring to a definite or indefinite element of a class, to a closer or more distant element, to an element belonging to a specified person or thing, to a particular number or quantity, etc.

Determiners have two main functions: **referring** and **quantifying**.

Examples of using **"Everything"** as **a determiner** and **a pronoun**:

- **I have everything in my life.** - an indefinite pronoun.
- **Everything good will come to you if you ask for it.** - an indefinite determiner.

Both **"all"** and **"everything"** as indefinite pronouns:

- **I couldn't tell her everything she wanted.**
- **I couldn't tell her all she wanted.**

As **"everything"** means **"all things"** we can use it in such examples:

- **"Everything beautiful comes from the heart."**
- **"All beautiful things come from the heart."**

[**Cambridge Grammar**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/all)